# Substring of char[] in c++

Tags: c++, char, substring

I have

```
  char t[200];
  cin.get(s, 200);
  int i = 5; 
  int j = 10;
```

Is there any simple way to get `substriing(i,j)` from `t` beside copying every element seperately to the another array? No `strings` etc. just `char t[200]`.

Comment: This is too vague. For what use ? You can simply pass the indices (start, end) to the function needing a substring, along with `t`...

Comment: The problem is that a standard C "string" is null-terminated.  This means that, if you for instance take a substring from 5 to 10, you not only must have the address of the 5th character (easy to accomplish) but you also must place a null after the 10th.  This will "stomp" on the original array.  So, to do a "proper" job the string must be copied.  (But if the rest of the array is a "throw-away" then you can work from the original buffer.)  (There is also the scope issue to consider, of course -- a char array (not a pointer) "exists" only within the method declaring it.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are allowed to modify `t`, you could set `t[j]` to `0` and then use `t + i` to get the substring.

If not, you are going to have to make a copy.

That said, why can't you just use `std::string` and save yourself the headache?

Answer (score 6):

```
char* substr(char* arr, int begin, int len)
{
    char* res = new char[len + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        res[i] = *(arr + begin + i);
    res[len] = 0;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail about your answer in addition to the code already there?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that i have to put 0 in the end and I always got strange results when printed copied arrays!

Answer (score 4):

If you need only to read the data then t+i is what you want, alas you'll have to manage the length of your substring...

```
char *sub = t+i;
int len = j-i;
printf("%.*s\n",len,sub);
```

If you need to have a distinct copy of the substring, then you must copy.

Answer (score 2):

This should work fine:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 char t[200];
 cin.get(t, 200);
 int i = 5; 
 int j = 10;
 char *to = (char*) malloc(j-i+1);
 strncpy(to, t+i, j-i);
 to[j-i]='\0';
 cout << to;
}
```

You can use `new` instead of `malloc` like this:

```
char* to = new char[j-i+1];
```

Comment: Why `malloc` when you have `new` ?

Answer (score 1):

This does not do any bounds checking to ensure the destination array is large enough

```
char newt[200];   
// copy j-i chars from position t+i to newt array
strncpy(newt, t + i, j-i);
// now null terminate
newt[j-i] = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two pointers to denote a range within the string.

```
char const * beg = t+i;
char const * end = t+j+1;    
std::cout.write(beg, end-beg);
```

Or you can use a class that encapsulates this idea.  There is [something like that](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3609.html) being proposed for the standard library.  In the meantime, you can write your own, or you can use one from a library.  For example, [`llvm::StringRef`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1StringRef.html).

```
llvm::StringRef sref(t+i, j+1-i);
std:cout << sref;
```